# java generics in action

Tags: java, generics, enums, java-6

I have the following code (java se 6):

```
import org.javatuples.Pair;

final SortedMap<Pair<AbstractEnum<?>, String>, AdapterObject> myMap = 
         new TreeMap<Pair<AbstractEnum<?>, String>();
myMap.put(Pair.with(SubTypeEnum.ITEM1, StringUtils.EMPTY), new AdapterObject());
```

AbstractEnum and SubTypeEnum are just:

```
public final class SubTypeEnum extends AbstractEnum<SubTypeEnum>
...
public abstract class AbstractEnum<T extends AbstractEnum<T>> implements Comparable<T>, Serializable
```

Now, the compiler says:

```
The method put(Pair<AbstractEnum<?>,String>, AdapterObject) in the type Map<Pair<AbstractEnum<?>,String>,AdapterObject> is not applicable for the arguments (Pair<SubTypeEnum,String>, new AdapterObject())
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the declaration to:

```
final SortedMap<Pair<? extends AbstractEnum<?>, String>, AdapterObject> myMap = 
            new TreeMap<Pair<? extends AbstractEnum<?>,String>, AdapterObject>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you'll find this

```
final SortedMap<Pair<AbstractEnum<?>, String>, AdapterObject> myMap = 
     new TreeMap<Pair<AbstractEnum<?>, String>();
```

should really be this

```
final SortedMap<Pair<AbstractEnum<SubTypeEnum>, String>, AdapterObject> myMap = 
     new TreeMap<Pair<AbstractEnum<SubTypeEnum>, String>();
```

Comment: No, the definition should stay generic. I want to call the `put()` method not only for `SubTypeEnum`, but also for `SubTypeEnum2`.

Comment: Make SubTypeEnum2 extend SubTypeEnum?

Comment: The problem is here `T extends AbstractEnum<T>` Your definition of the generic requires that T be a subclass of `AbstractEnum`. Why not just use `T`?

Answer (score 0):

Just like how `String` is a subtype of `Object`, but `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`,

`SubTypeEnum` is a subtype of `AbstractEnum<SubTypeEnum>`, but `Pair<SubTypeEnum,String>` is not a subtype of `Pair<AbstractEnum<SubTypeEnum>,String>` or `Pair<AbstractEnum<?>,String>` or `Pair<anything other than SubTypeEnum,String>`

What you should do depends on what your intended use of this type is. If you want to only read the enum out of the pair (and never put it in), then `Pair<? extends AbstractEnum<?>, String>` will work.